# Function to create separate DFs based on column value

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr

I have a demography table that consist of demography record of different patients. In demography each patient has the record that at which hospital patient is registered **(Hospital_ID)**.

I am filtering the demography table by **Hospital_ID == A434** and then merging the Demography df with **patient_prescription** by **Pat_ID** for each hospital. By the end I will have merged patient record for each hospital ID. In real data I have around 2000 patients and 270 distinct Hospital_ID. Doing it manually for each hospital_id is not a good idea.

What I want is how to create a function for this so that it runs once and give me 270 DFs as output for each **Hospital_ID**. Below is the example and output of dfs.

```
library(dplyr)

Demography <- read.table(text="
Pat_ID  Gender  Hospital_ID
P1  M   A434
P2  F   A232
P3  F   A331
P4  M   A434
P5  F   A21
P6  M   A232", header=TRUE)

Patient_Prescription <- read.table(text="
Pat_ID  Prescription_ID     Prescription
P1  221     Hydrolin
P2  332     ospamox
P3  331     Paxix
P4  334     Danitol
P5  441     Soapsomede
P6  3311    'Dentol hydro'", header = TRUE)
```

| Pat_ID | Gender | Hospital_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | M | A434 |
| P2 | F | A232 |
| P3 | F | A331 |
| P4 | M | A434 |
| P5 | F | A21 |
| P6 | M | A232 |

| Pat_ID | Prescription_ID | Prescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 221 | Hydrolin |
| P2 | 332 | ospamox |
| P3 | 331 | Paxix |
| P4 | 334 | Danitol |
| P5 | 441 | Soapsomede |
| P6 | 3311 | Dentol hydro |

Two Output DFs

| Pat_ID | Hospital_ID | Prescription | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | A434 | Hydrolin | M |
| P4 | A434 | Danitol | M |

| Pat_ID | Hospital_ID | Prescription | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P2 | A232 | Ospamox | F |
| P6 | A232 | Dentol hydro | M |

Comment: Please correct the errors in your code to create your test data.  Using the tidyverse, `group_map()` or similar will make tour task simple.

Comment: @Limey I added reproducible ones :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
left_join(Demography, Patient_Prescription, by = "Pat_ID") |> 
group_split(Hospital_ID)
```

or alternatively, you could do:

```
library(magrittr)

left_join(Demography, Patient_Prescription, by = "Pat_ID") %>%
{split(., .$Hospital_ID)}
```

Comment: The second ones changes it to Large List. Can we change the list to DFs ?

Comment: @UsmanYousafZai what do you mean by "Large List"

Comment: because I have 270 distinct Hospital_ID , when I run b<- left_join(Demography, Patient_Prescription, by = "Pat_ID") %>%
{split(., .$Hospital_ID)}    It gives me Large list(269 elements, 931.5 MB). This is written on the left side of the df(b) in the enviornment

Comment: What were you expecting? I thought you wanted a list of dataframes, which from what it sounds like, is what you got

Comment: Okay i guess i should not use the word "List" in my question. Because i didn't meant it by programming point of view(list). So actually I need 270 dataframes based on Hospital_Id. I will edit my question.

Comment: in what format would you like them in?

Comment: I want to have 270 DFs. I will paste the output I got in my question. So its easier for you.

Comment: @UsmanYousafZai it's a list of dataframes! Which is what you wanted. The dataframes have to go in something

Comment: Okay, how can view these dfs, because I want to save them as .cvs files.

Comment: you mean csv files?

Comment: re: saving them all - you can run `map2(b, names(a),\(x, n) x |> write_csv(paste0(n, ".csv")))`

Comment: re: viewing them - there's a bunch of ways, depending on which ones you're wanting to view. One option is `View(b$A10)`

Comment: the saving command is giving error.   is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254946/discussion-between-mark-and-usman-yousafzai).